# Alternatives to `clear(function_name)` to remove function from RAM?

Tags: matlab

As stated in   [MATLAB's FAQ](http://www.isr.umd.edu/~austin/ence202.d/matlab-faq.html#1.3.3.1.),

> 1.3.3.1. Why, when I edit a function file in MATLAB, is the change not seen by MATLAB until everything is cleared or MATLAB is restarted?
>
> When you write an M-file in MATLAB, you can either write a script or a
>   function. The difference is that a script is read from the disk and
>   parsed line by line each time it is called. A function is loaded into
>   RAM for execution. Because it is loaded into RAM, when you edit a
>   function, that change is not loaded into RAM until a call to the new
>   function is made.
>
> To get MATLAB to recognize your edited function, type
>
> ```
> clear functions to clear all functions, or
>
> clear <function name> to clear just your function out of RAM.
> ```

This is a major pain when I'm developing a function & editing it repeatedly (I use an external editor most of the time).  I was thinking of putting in a final line, at least during debug, like

`clear(myfunc)`

but I'm concerned about unwanted side effects. Does anyone know if there are any?

Further, I'd rather have a way to configure MATLAB so it doesn't automatically store called functions in RAM once the top-level function (i.e. the one called from the console) terminates.  Is that even possible?

EDIT: I should mention that MATLAB's behavior is inconsistent. Sometimes my edits take effect once I save the m-file, other times they don't **even if** I'm editing with the MATLAB IDE editor window.

Answer (score 0):

> In all honesty MATLAB has a very powerful editor so you really should
>   be using it. It will make you life easier. (just an opinion)

- Unless you are running the code by stepping through it no change to code will be run until the code is re-run (preferably with a cleared workspace).
- `clear(myfunc)` will clear the variables created by that function in upto that point. You can add at the end of any function or script `clear variableA variableB` for all variables you want cleared at the end. This will give you control to only clear what you want. Once variables are cleared the only effect will be that if those variables are called again later in the code an error will occur since they no longer exist.
- If your simply testing that particular function and want to save time by not calling inputs each time and want to clear the workspace and command window at the same time. You can add the following code just beneath the function definition.

If you leave the following code and call the function from another function or script, the code will be ignored as long as the inputs are available to it externally. Anything you add to the if statement will only occur when you call the function with no inputs [doc nargin](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nargin.html). You could add it to the top level function and you would simply press the run button or f5 without having to type in the command window to run the code.

```
function [ output1, output2 ] = blah( input1, input2 )
if nargin == 0
   clc
   clear all
   %above two lines will clear the workspace and command window when you run
   %the function 

   %define function inputs

   %(optionally add the following to behave as if you inserted a breakpoint 
   %in the location just before the error occurred (great for debugging)
   db stop if error
end
```

*you can also add a short-cut to snippets of code up in the top right of the MATLAB interface to clear the workspace etc when they are clicked.

Answer (score 0):

***Hackish**** idea for this:

> I'd rather have a way to configure MATLAB so it doesn't automatically store called functions in RAM once the top-level function (i.e. the one called from the console) terminates. Is that even possible?

* This is the sort of thing I might use, while advising others on why it is a bad idea, also probably uses undocumented (thus unreliable) things.

---

Specifically if your using an external editor I guess your going to have to *click* on the command window to run the function...

```
commandWindowHandle = ...
handle(com.mathworks.mde.desk.MLDesktop.getInstance.getClient('Command Window'...
.getComponent(0).getComponent(0).getComponent(0),'CallbackProperties');

commandWindowHandle.MouseClickedCallback = 'clear functions'
```

It doesn't clear the function definitions on exiting a function rather on clicking on the command window

*note: the callback will not fire if a function is currently running*

For a potentially more reliable but more wasteful version:

```
commandWindowHandle.KeyPressedCallback= 'clear functions'
```

will help* ensure definitions are clear, but is wasteful as every keystroke will run 'clear functions'... although after one keystroke this will be quicker as there will be no functions in memory!

* No guarantee I know there are ways in which this could fail... having at least 1 keystroke in the command window after the previous function call has finished would be advisable!

---

To disable these set the callback to empty string `''`

```
commandWindowHandle.MouseClickedCallback = ''
commandWindowHandle.KeyPressedCallback= ''
```

---